# Error -4058 Npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, adonisjs

Boa tarde,

ultimamente, quando tento instalar uma dependência via npm install, as vezes acontece isso, já[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui resolvi uma vez excluindo a node_modules e dando um npm install, porem não está mais resolvendo. Alguém sabe pq isso ocorre e como resolver?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá!

No Stackoverflow.com tem uma solução para sua resposta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620780/cant-install-any-npm-package-error-4058

Consiste em deletar seu `package-lock.json` e tentar reinstalar o pacote.

- Detalhe importante é certificar-se de não ter nenhum outro processo Node rodando, mais detalhes estão aqui também: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17444

Comment: Muito Obrigado :D

Comment: Por nada @A.Otavio disponha!